# R: loading libraries vs specifying them as Imports in the Description/Namespace File

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I have a bunch of packages which I need for my code:

```
library(GenomicRanges, GenomicFeatures, biomaRt,knitr, ggplot2,gridSVG,gridExtra)
```

Once, when I wrap my code into a R package und put all up-mentioned packages in the Imports slot of the description file, and also the corresponding stuff in the Namespace file,
I get errors like:

```
## Error: could not find function 'ggplotGrob'
## Error: could not find function 'pushViewport'
## Error: could not find function 'newXMLNode'
```

Any hints in which direction I should go?

My description file:

```
Package: myQC package
Type: Package
Title: Quality Control 
Version: 0.99
Date: 2013-03-12
Author: Stefanie 
Maintainer: my_email_address
Description: blabla
License: GPL-2
Depends: R (>= 2.15.3)
Imports: GenomicRanges, GenomicFeatures, biomaRt, knitr, xtable, ggplot2, gridSVG,gridExtra, IRanges
```

My Namespace File:

```
import(GenomicRanges)
import(GenomicFeatures)
import(biomaRt)
import(knitr)
import(xtable)
import(ggplot2)
import(gridSVG)
import(gridExtra)
import(IRanges)
```

Actually I don't need all of the functionality of these packages, so later on I will specify which functions/methods I will import. This was just a first shot..
best,

Comment: Please provide the actual DESCRIPTION file and the NAMESPACE.

Comment: When do you get the errors?  When building? When installing? When attempting to use some functions in your package?

Comment: R CMD build, check and INSTALL are fine. After loading the package, I call a functions which should output an html report. Within this report up-mentioned errors arise.